# NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for - Rails 5.1.6 upgraded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I got this error in rspec while I do not have any variable or method with that name, I even searched all over the project. This happens when I run Rspec for all the test cases, while individual test cases work fine.

I was upgrading the ruby on rails version from ruby 2.3.3 rails 4.1.6. and I upgraded the version one by one, and I have all test passed after reaching rails 5.1.6 with ruby 2.4.5 I got this error. while all the tests also worked normally with the same ruby version and rails 5.0.7

Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this.

I rebuild the spec_helper.rb again using bin/rspec --init and I added the dependencies and I have a longer trace now

```
NameError:
  undefined local variable or method `app' for #<Devise::Mailer:0x00007fd3271928f8>
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test/methods.rb:30:in `build_rack_mock_session'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test/methods.rb:26:in `rack_mock_session'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test/methods.rb:41:in `build_rack_test_session'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test/methods.rb:37:in `rack_test_session'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test/methods.rb:45:in `current_session'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb:18:in `assign_controller'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/base.rb:211:in `initialize'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:106:in `initialize'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:72:in `new'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:72:in `view_context'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:97:in `_render_template'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:945:in `block in collect_responses_from_templates'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:942:in `each'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:942:in `each'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:942:in `map'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:942:in `collect_responses_from_templates'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:927:in `collect_responses'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:830:in `mail'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb:19:in `devise_mail'
# ./app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:12:in `confirmation_instructions'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:23:in `block in process'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:15:in `handle_exceptions'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:22:in `process'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:609:in `block in process'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:608:in `process'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:105:in `block in processed_mailer'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:104:in `tap'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:104:in `processed_mailer'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/actionmailer-5.1.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:95:in `deliver_now'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:200:in `send_devise_notification'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:121:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:183:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:260:in `block in conditional'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:343:in `committed!'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:86:in `commit_records'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:178:in `block in commit_transaction'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:168:in `commit_transaction'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:207:in `block in within_new_transaction'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block in save'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
# ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_messages_spec.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_messages_spec.rb:89:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_messages_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/melsatar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
```

Comment: you should have some stacktrace pointing to the file an line that produces the error

Comment: When I run individual spec for the test cases, it is successful, the main issue when I run all test cases together actually

Comment: @arieljuod do you know what could be the cause for this?

Comment: the error should have a staktrace pointing to a file and line number where it's trying to use that app variable, you are not showing the full error, just the error message, so no idea where's that comming from, show the full error with stacktrace and all

Comment: @arieljuod, I added the full trace in the question

Comment: @MohamedSami The error points to: `app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:12`. What's in that file? What's on line 12? And the problem was originally triggered from `spec/controllers/answers_controller_spec.rb:150`. What is this test? What's on line 150?

Comment: If the test passes in isolation, but not when you run the whole file, you could try debugging further with `rspec --bisect`.

Comment: @TomLord app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb:12 is the normal devise mailer,

Comment: The error is repeated actually with every single test case, this is only one of the examples

Comment: hmmm, I'm guessing that you used some devise command to copy the gem's mailer class into your app folder and maybe you have an outdated version, check if you have the mailer inside app/mailers/devise and if it's differente from the one in the gem

Comment: @arieljuod That is true, I have the mailer inside app/mailers/devise and I checked the mailer version and it is the same only I added few lines       headers "X-SMTPAPI" => {"category"=> "Confirmation"}.to_json
      opts[:cc] = 'email@here'

Comment: https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/blob/6c07bf53adf4a4082e206561f5b9b43142fdc821/lib/rack/test/methods.rb#L5-L18

Comment: ...So the question comes back, for the third time, to: Can you please provide a [mcve]? It looks like you're doing something "wrong" in the tests, like trying to use `rack-test` without defining an `app`. But I don't know what's wrong, because you haven't shared any code.

Comment: @TomLord I have shared the trace error for that. But can you guide me more, what do you mean by defining the app? I have the rspec_helper.rb which has the configuration as the normal case.

Comment: @TomLord, I added a new trace, what do you think?

Comment: @arieljuod, I added a new trace, what do you think?

Comment: @MohamedSami So the error also stems from the `spec/mailers/user_mailer_messages_spec.rb` test. OK... But how can I *reproduce* the problem? What code is in that file? An error trace is helpful to see what triggers it, but that file could contain literally anything, for all I know.

Comment: Try to delete everything you can from that file, and from `rails_helper.rb`/`spec_helper.rb`, whilst still reproducing the error. Show a **minimal** test example that triggers it. Most likely, by the time you've actually cut it down to a minimal example, it should be quite obvious what the likely culprit is. Apparently it's got something to do with your use of `rack-test`, for starters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184055/discussion-between-mohamed-sami-and-tom-lord).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the issue was one of the controllers' files, I was including a depreciated Rack::Test::Methods which made the conflict. If you experience a similar issue, remove it in rails 5.1

```
include Rack::Test::Methods
```

Comment: For anyone else banging their heads against the wall getting the "NameError: undefined local variable or method \`app'" error. It also happens when you are running all your tests at once (multiple files) and one of them does an `include Rack::Test::Methods` - the include "infects" the other tests. So the symptom is that all tests pass when the files are run individually through `rspec`, but then they fail with the "no app" error when run together. At least this happens with `rails 3.0.9` and `rspec 3.0`